# Why wont my cursor change to a custom image?

Tags: html, css

I want the cursor to change to an image when you hover over the div #gamespace. I also tried adding a separate div#gamespace:hover selector with the same cursor attribute but that didn't work either.

Here's my code:

```css
div#gamespace {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  cursor: url(../img/baseballBat.png), auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="contenta">
    <h1><span>Home Run Derby</span></h1>
    <p></p>
    <div id="controls">
      <span id="score">0 pts</span>
      <button type="button" id="start_button">Start!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="timer">
      30 Seconds Left
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gamespace"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly if I change the cursor url to another image (I used https://placekitten.com/g/20/20). Is it possible the path to your image isn't correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if I change the URL of the cursor image. Your image path is probably incorrect or inaccessible. Check whether your image is in the folder *above* your HTML file and, if you're using a web server, make sure it's within your web root and is publicly accessible.

If your image isn't in the folder above your HTML file you need to either move it or correct the path in your CSS.

```css
div#gamespace {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  cursor: url(https://placekitten.com/g/40/40), auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="contenta">
    <h1><span>Home Run Derby</span></h1>
    <p></p>
    <div id="controls">
      <span id="score">0 pts</span>
      <button type="button" id="start_button">Start!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="timer">
      30 Seconds Left
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gamespace"></div>
</div>
```